# jQuery css() function onclick again

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#FlatCheckbox").click(function(){
        $("#style1").css("margin-top",10);
    });
});
```

```html
 <h2>
       <input type='checkbox' id="FlatCheckbox" class="FlatCheckbox" onClick=''>
          AAA
 </h2>

<div id='style1'>
      <input type='button' onClick='' class='AddBtn' value='Apply / Save'>
</div>
```

Here's my question:
Click the checkbox first time changed the button's css, but how to change back(reset) button's css after click checkbox again?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: You need to toggle on the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of inline style like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FlatCheckbox").click(function() {
    $("#style1").toggleClass('clicked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
       <input type='checkbox' id="FlatCheckbox" class="FlatCheckbox" onClick=''>
          AAA
 </h2>

<div id='style1'>
  <input type='button' onClick='' class='AddBtn' value='Apply / Save'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better  to use toggleClass In this context

```
$("#FlatCheckbox").click(function() {
    $("#style1").toggleClass("active");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltu2L7h1/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using boolean flag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var m = true;
    $("#FlatCheckbox").click(function(){
        if(m) {
            $("#style1").css("margin-top",10);
        } else {
            $('#style1').css('margin-top',0);
        }  
        m = !m;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only one property is margin-top, then you may achieve that like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=0;
        $("#FlatCheckbox").click(function(){
           if(i++%1==0)
            $("#style1").css("margin-top",10);
           else
            $("#style1").css("margin-top",0);
        });
    });
```

or use toggleClass

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#FlatCheckbox").click(function() {
     $("#style1").toggleClass('marginable', this.checked);
   });
 });
```

and this css

```
.marginable{margin-top:10px}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't exist any function `.toggleCss()` but you can use a `[toggleClass][1]` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#FlatCheckbox").click(function(){
            $("#style1").toggleClass("styled");
        });
});
```

```css
.styled{
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  <input type='checkbox' id="FlatCheckbox" class="FlatCheckbox">
  AAA
</h2>

<div id='style1'>
  <input type='button' class='AddBtn' value='Apply / Save'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggleClass('newMargin')`

```
.newMargin{
    margin-top : 10
}
```

or,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var initMargin = $("#style1").css("margin-top");
    $("#FlatCheckbox").click(function(){
        var currentMargin = $("#style1").css("margin-top");
        $("#style1").css("margin-top",currentMargin == initMargin? "10px": initMargin);
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var initMargin = $("#style1").css("margin-top");
    $("#FlatCheckbox").change(function(){
      debugger;
        var currentMargin = $("#style1").css("margin-top");
        $("#style1").css("marginTop",currentMargin == initMargin? "10px": initMargin);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <h2>
       <input type='checkbox' id="FlatCheckbox" class="FlatCheckbox" onClick=''>
          AAA
 </h2>

<div id='style1'>
      <input type='button' onClick='' class='AddBtn' value='Apply / Save'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See @AnoopJoshi answer. Otherwise, if you want to change the syle, you can implement the toggle yourself with a boolen flag.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {


  var isToggled = false;

  $("#FlatCheckbox").click(function() {
    isToggled = !isToggled;
    $("#style1").css("margin-top", isToggled ? 10 : 0);
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2><input type='checkbox' id="FlatCheckbox" class="FlatCheckbox" onClick=''>AAA</h2>

<div id='style1'>
  <input type='button' onClick='' class='AddBtn' value='Apply / Save'>
</div>
```